# Find and return the k:th element

Tags: java

Find and return the k:th element (counting from zero, as usual in computer science) from the infinite sequence of all prime numbers 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, ... This method may assume that k is nonnegative.

isPrime works, kthPrime compiles but it runs forever... not sure what to do to make it faster

```
public static boolean isPrime(int n){
    if (n<2) return false;
    for (int i=2;i<=Math.sqrt(n);i++){
        if (n%i==0)
          return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public static int kthPrime(int k){
    int counter=0;
    for (int i=0;i<=Integer.MAX_VALUE;i++){
        if (isPrime(i)){
            counter++;
            if(counter==k)
                return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

UnitTest:

```
@Test public void kthPrimeTest() {
    CRC32 check = new CRC32();
    for(int k = 0; k < 30_000; k++) {
        check.update(Primes.kthPrime(k));
    }
    assertEquals(3080752681L, check.getValue());
}
```

Comment: With what input of `k` does it run "forever"

Comment: any...I tried as small as 20. It will be tested for 30_000 though

Comment: A value of `20` finishes almost instantly for me. Are you sure that you're running the code that you think you are?

Comment: It works perfectly fine on my system up to `k` of `500000`, `20` is almost instant.

Comment: yes i'm certain.. so odd. thanks for checking.

Comment: It makes no sense to me to run that in a loop. When you want up to the 20th prime, then why calculate each single prime in a loop instead of returning all found primes in `kthPrime` up to the given value?

Comment: I would think that `2` would be the `first` prime, not the `zeroth`.  In CS, indices typically start at `0`.  But when talking about `ordinal` positions, it is customary to use `1` as the starting point (because applications are used by non-CS folks). Not certain what your requirement is but I when asked for the `Kth` prime I would return prime at index `k-1`.  Even for computer scientists, it is usually assumed 1 is the starting point for ordinals.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the case when its run at `k = 0`.

Add this to your `kthPrime` code at the start of the method:

```
if (k == 0) {
    return 2;
}
```

This will add a check if `k` is `0` so that it will not run forever.

See this block:

```
if (isPrime(i)){
   counter++;
   if(counter==k)
       return i;           
}
```

Here you can see when `k` is `0`, counter will be incremented to `1`, making `counter == k` into `1 == 0` which will never be true, thus the code will not exit until it hits the `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which will take a *very* long time.

Comment: Other than invalid value of 0th prime it's the right answer.

Comment: You are returning 0 from kthPrime not isPrime.

Comment: `kthPrime(0)` should return 2 as 2 is the zeroth prime.

Comment: @Piotr Ah my apologies, I thought the point of the code was to return the _count_ of the primes under `k` not the value itself, I forgot.  I understand your point now.